# Flutter : when i tried to pick an excel file its show's error

Tags: android, excel, flutter

when i tried to pick an excel file its show's this (When i try in flutter web it works fine) :

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

that my code:

```
MyButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      var pickedFile = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                        type: FileType.custom,
                        allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
                        allowMultiple: false,
                      );
                      if (pickedFile != null) {
                        dataSend(
                          pickedFile,
                          selectedSite!,
                          selectedAppareil!,
                          _getValueText(
                            config.calendarType,
                            debutLocation,
                          ),
                          _getValueText(
                            config.calendarType,
                            finLocation,
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  textButton: 'Import Excel file'),
```

and this my dataSend method:

```
dataSend(FilePickerResult pickedFile, String site, String appareil,
    String debutLocation, String finLocation) {
  CollectionReference sewsDatabase =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('sewsDatabase');

  List<String> rowdetail = [];
  int? col;
  var bytes = pickedFile.files.single.bytes;
> var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes!); // error in this line
  var nSerie = [];
  for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
    try {
      for (var row in excel.tables[table]!.rows) {
        rowdetail.add(row.elementAt(0)!.value.toString());
        col = row.length;
      }
      print(rowdetail);
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

i try rewrite my code but everything looks good(its works in flutter web) how can i solve this in android

Comment: Can you show me your pubspec.yaml file where you add the assets.

Comment: why assets because i face this problem when i pick file from my phone my assets have only one path(assets/images/)

Comment: bytes is null it seems. Check for null first.